# Can I call members of class by template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning C++.
 My question is related to how to attach data classes which are same classes but different data to a class. If I can call these member by template, I can reduce coding. To explain them. please see code below.

The following two codes show what kind of Book and Game a Person has.

The first one is implemented by inheritance of ItemHolder. And Person_Inheritance class can call Book.print() or Game.print() through template. So it needs only one template function to call them. This code reduction can have much better effect when I need to call some functions under ItemHolder.

However, Person and Book/Game are has-a relation-ship. I have learned that I should use composition when they are has-a relation-ship. So I needed to rewrite code by composition.

The second code which does same thing as the first code but it is implemented by composition. The point is the class needs two separated functions to call Book.print() or Game.print(). When I need to call some functions under ItemHolder class, I need write almost all function multiple times. It leads to much more coding.

In a summary of my question,

(1) Can I call data members of a class by a template function?

(2) Is it necessary to keep the rules; that is, is-a relatoin-ship need inheritance and has-a relation-ship needs composition?

It may be a long question. Thank you for reading them. And if you tell me your solution or suggestion, I thank you again.

Base classes :

```
class Book {
public:
    Book() = default;
    virtual ~Book() = default;
    void print(void) { std::cout << "Bible" << std::endl; };
};

class Game {
public:
    Game() = default;
    virtual ~Game() = default;
    void print(void) { std::cout << "Pokemon" << std::endl; };
};

template <typename Item>
class ItemHolder {
public :
    ItemHolder() = default;
    virtual ~ItemHolder() = default;
    void tellItem(void) {
        item_.print();
    }
private :
    Item item_;
};
```

Implementation by Inheritance :

```
class Person_Inheritance : public ItemHolder<Book>,
                           public ItemHolder<Game> {
public:
    Person_Inheritance() = default;
    virtual ~Person_Inheritance() = default;
    template <typename T_Item>
    void showItem() {
        ItemHolder<T_Item>::tellItem();
    }
};

void test_0(void) {
    Person_Inheritance John;
    John.showItem<Book>();
    John.showItem<Game>();    
}
```

Implementation by Composition

```
class Person_Composition {
public:
    Person_Composition() = default;
    virtual ~Person_Composition() = default;

    void showBook() { book_.tellItem(); }
    void showGame() { game_.tellItem(); }

private :
    ItemHolder<Book> book_;
    ItemHolder<Game> game_;
};

void test_1(void) {
    Person_Composition Bill;
    Bill.showBook();
    Bill.showGame();
}
```

Comment: If a data member is callable then you can call it. For example, an `int` data member is not callable.

Comment: Why not both?  [Just turn `Person_Inheritance` into an intermediate class, which `Person_Composition` has a single variable of (instead of two `ItemHolder`s).  `Person_Composition` can then supply `showItem()` as a wrapper function](http://ideone.com/BGLADG).

Comment: Also, as an aside, in C++, `void f()` and `void f(void)` are exactly identical to each other (specifically, ["A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is equivalent to an empty parameter list."](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#4)), except if the code is compiled as C code.  Of the two, `void f()` is _usually_ preferred for pure C++ code, but this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank everyone for answring. I am afraid my question might not be clear. The answer by MSalters is what I would like to know. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example (composition), it's unavoidable that you mention `book_` and `game_`. There's no workaround, given that class.

There are at least two work-arounds. C++ has `private` inheritance, which does not imply an IS-A relationship. It would allow you to reuse the first example.

Secondly, you could use composition and have a single `std::tuple<ItemHolder<Book>, ItemHolder<Game>>` member.

Comment: thank you for answering, I will use 'private' inheritance.